# pip3 not working after reinstall

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, python3, pip

I have recently reinstalled python3 on my Ubuntu Xenial Gnome system using apt. I also installed python3-pip. However, now pip3 no longer works. Attempting to run pip3 gives a strange error: `bash: /home/sirnapkin1334/.local/bin/pip3: No such file or directory`
I find this strange, as python3 -m pip works fine, but not pip3, which also gives an atypical error message. `locate pip3` gives no output and `which pip3` gives the path `/usr/bin/pip3`. If you run that path, pip3 works fine, but I don't know why the pip3 command points to a nonexistant directory. Does anyone know how to update this pip3 command to point to the correct location?

Comment: Fix your PATH. See https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: Well, I set it with export, but now I have to use $pip3

Comment: Then you haven't exported it correctly.

Comment: It appears that uninstalling pip via itself and reinstalling via apt-get fixed the issue, though I am not fully sure why. Can I 'close' the question?